# Low performance when Second screen only

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I know this problem has found is share of interest on the internet in the recent years. But I couldn't solve my issue using these answers.

Now I managed to enclose the problem into a few parameters, so maybe I can solve this once and for all.

When connecting to a second screen (HDMI and thunderbolt), there is absolutely no problem with **Extend** and **Duplicate**. Works as intended. When **Second screen only** is chosen however, even the windows explorer stutters with low fps. This issue resolves when using full screen applications.

So I guess the main question is, why my second screen gives 60 FPS on heavy demanding games, but gives 5 FPS on windows explorer, or anything that is not full screen. The first thing comes to mind is the integrated graphics still trying to handle non-full screen applications, but the screen is connected to the dedicated graphics.

[image: Image description]

**System Properties:**

```
MSI Gaming laptop (2016)
Windows 10 Pro (Latest version)

Intel 6700 HQ

Nvidia GTX 1060 (3 GB)
Intel® HD Graphics 530
(Both drivers up to date)
```

I won't give details of the second screen, because the same behavior happens in all external displays I tried. But I can say that both screens are *1080p* and *60 Hz*.

Happens with both HDMI and thunderbolt.

Comment: With thunderbolt, chances are it's running on the intel adaptor. On windows 10 it's possible to run different monitors or apps on different gpus. Not an answer on it's own but https://superuser.com/questions/1604711/can-i-run-programs-on-a-specific-gpu might be a useful starting point/mitigation

Comment: Why do you think Explorer needs more than 5fps? it's not really doing anything, so spinning its wheels at 60fps is a complete waste of energy. If you have a floating fps viewer you can try grabbing a window & dragging it swiftly around the screen. You'll see the fps lift to compensate, then when you stop doing that, it will drop back down to about 5 again.

Comment: @Tetsujin Then why all the Windows computers in the world, try to avoid giving 5 fps to the user in the explorer ? I don't have a fps viewer, I am saying there is something wrong performance-wise with this. Let me remind you this low fps happens only in *second screen only*. Where you would expect higher performance than *Extend*, because only one screen is being rendered. Also, the issue is not limited to Explorer as I mentioned in the question. I can't watch videos without making it full screen if I want to watch it with more than 7-8 FPS.