# Are MoBo "integrated graphics" used if separate graphics card is present?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard

I have a motherboard with "integrated Intel graphics" and an HDMI output.  I add PCI graphics card, which has its own GPU, RAM, and HDMI output.  If I leave my display connected to the the motherboard's HDMI port then is the graphics card doing anything?

If I connect one display to the motherboard HDMI port and another to the graphics card HDMI port then is one display being driven by the motherboard's "integrated" graphics and the other by the graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no - there's a few things that determine it. With 'modern' systems with the iGPU on the same package as the processor - there's usually a bios setting that determines this and the name varies -on an older system this was called [iGPU multi monitor](https://superuser.com/a/523929/10165).

*If* this is turned on and your HDMI cable is plugged into your onboard graphics *and* you're running an application on the discrete GPU - [programs can be set to run on the discrete GPU](https://superuser.com/questions/1604711/can-i-run-programs-on-a-specific-gpu/1604714#1604714) with the iGPU outputting the graphics (or vice versa) even if they run on the gpu connected to the display they are on by default on windows. Linux may work differently.

Quite often your discrete card is the 'default' so its possible you may get no output from your iGPU output

if memory serves, you can check this from your task manager in windows 10 and better.

As such you *can* use both and you would need to configure your system appropriately

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have your monitor connected to the MB's video jack then the intergrated becomes default. However if you connect it to the GPU's video port then the GPU becomes default. Now if you're running a program that requires GPU power then they'll usually allow you to select which one to use in their settings, while others by default will look for the GPU in your system before they go for the intergrated graphics. ..