# Why is my GTX 970 working with the motherboard HDMI port, and why is my iGPU disabled on Asus ROG Strix Z690-A gaming WIFI motherboard?

Tags: hdmi, gpu, pci-express, intel

I wanted to test the integrated graphics on my i7 12700 K CPU, so I unplugged the HDMI from the GTX 970 card and plugged it in the motherboard HDMI port. To my surprise, the 970 card was being output through the motherboard HDMI port, and the intel integrated graphics was disabled. I ran benchmarks and found that the GTX 970 was getting better benchmark scores than it ever has. It also shows that it is using shared memory with my system.

Is this a new function of PCIe 5.0?

I read that someone moved their video card to the PCIe 4.0 slot and the integrated graphics was enabled after doing that.

Comment: `It also shows that it is using shared memory with my system` just like the iGPU would? what makes you believe the 970 is "outputtted" through the motherboard HDMI?

Comment: Sorry for the spelling. Running the display only from the motherboard HDMI port. SuperPosition Benchmark runs at 60 FPS on 1080 medium mode. GPU meter shows the GTX 970 card being used. Also the 970 card fans kick on and, as far as I am aware, the intel UHD 770 graphics would not get frame rates that high. Would be lucky to see 5 or 10 FPS. My games are running a little faster than they have. The intel Ark Control software shows that the GTX 970 adapter is being used instead of the intel UHD 770.

Comment: OK, never seen that personally, but then I haven't uses intel in many years

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1604711/can-i-run-programs-on-a-specific-gpu/1604714#1604714 related - basically windows runs it on the 'best' GPU, in theory, but there's other elements,like rendering some things on the GPU the app is on. Better benchmarks might be due to lower overheads?

Comment: “Is this a new function of PCIe 5.0?” - Your GPU doesn’t support it.

Comment: Ok, so I have been trying to figure this out, and possibly the higher scores are due to the extra shared memory. I have researched this and this does seem to only happen with newer motherboards when the card is plugged into a PCI Extended 5.0 slot. I believe my board has a 4.0 slot and a 3.0 slot, if I'm not mistaken. I could test this by moving the card. I think this could be intel offloading processes that the card normally would do itself. So I guess I will move the card to another slot and report back. Also I'm not exactly sure that games are running faster. Only valid test could validate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer. It is IOMMU that supports GPU passthough. The AI in my motherboard is disabling iGPU by default. I did plug the GTX 970 into the PCIe 3.0 slot and was still seeing GPU passthough. There are so many options in this bios that I missed finding the option to manually enable iGPU multi monitor, and with the AI disabling it, it defaults to IOMMU GPU passthough. So It has nothing to do with the version of PCIe

Comment: This is hard to believe. But, on the negative side, I have to remove my video card to test on board graphics. iGPU. Things look better and run better if I plug into the mthbrd. It is weird plus my scores on bench-test come back better? I don't get it but it works