# Low FPS while using Lumion on Windows

Tags: windows, memory, performance

I use a windows laptop with these specs:

- AMD Ryzen 7 5800H,
- Nvidia GeForce 3050 Ti and
- 16 Gb RAM
- 500Gb SSD.

I’m trying to use Lumion, but the FPS is really low (1-5) making it impossible to work with .

Here are some things I tried to remedy the problem:

- In the application I have set the graphics settings to minimal, but the fps is still too low.
- I cleaned memory, (now I have 156 Gb free) and also I cleaned RAM. It shows that I have very little memory space (like 100Mb).

How can I improve the frame rates for this app on Windows?

Comment: @samh ive edited the question to be a little more clear. Seems to be on topic.

Comment: Edit your question to include your Passmark score. 3050 Ti isn’t a very good card specification wise.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid my “off topic” comment was based on this being posted in apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: What version of windows might be useful. There's a few security settings worth turning off in 11 like memory integrity

Comment: Also, I wonder which GPU its using -you can set it explicitly,  see https://superuser.com/a/1604714/10165